# Why does jQuery work on one page and not another?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox-2

I am using a number of jQuery scripts on a site, including Fancybox. Everything works,  except on a page with a form. I have never seen a static form conflict with jQuery before. At first I thought it was the path to the jQuery, but there are pages at the same level and one will work and the other will not.

For example, on [this page](http://opteracreative.com/~mac/who-we-are/contributors), if you click on **ArtStart Our Newsletter** Fancybox works fine, but if you do the same thing on [this page](http://opteracreative.com/~mac/artists/submit-artist-profile) the same form does not open in Fancybox and I get the following error:

> Fancybox is not a function

Normally this tells me that the link to jquery.fancybox is broken or there is a conflict. I have changed the $ to jQuery to prevent conflicts, but it hasn't made any difference. Also, all pages pull from the same embedded code for the script links.

Here is the code for Fancybox:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            width       : 600,
            height      : 800
            });
        });
</script>
```

I would appreciate some assistance resolving this.

Thanks

Comment: works fine for me if I run it from the console

Comment: Fancybox is working fine for me in that another page too? Does this problem occur in specific browsers, like IE?

Comment: Tested in chrome..works fine for me on both the pages. Clear your browser cache and try testing again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 instances of `jQuery(document).ready` in your head, try moving all the scripts into one `jQuery(document).ready` this should solve the issue of getting `.fancybox` method not been recognized

Comment: Thanks for the speedy and precise response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have several jQuery(document).ready, and some of them are explicitly aliasing the $ while others aren't.

Besides, somewhere in the middle of your code you are loading jQuery again

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://opteracreative.com/~mac/?ACT=10&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,button,dialog,datepicker&plugin=markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&file=underscore,cp/date&v=1388434578&use_live_url=y&include_jquery=y"></script>
```

I believe the global jQuery object does load its plugins, but just then you replace it with a new one without plugins.